# Get target attributes in Jquery fancybox image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
<a  data-id="oNz" class="fancybox-buttons"data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="/Images/Axbaz.jpg">
        <img title="Love" class="ajax" src="/thumbs/Axbaz.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

I'm customizing [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5) Jquery plugin...
I want to (Get) alert `data-id="oNz"` property value and more target attributes When image showing or changing...
what `this` selector in [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5) plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this.element)` to refer to `$(this)` inside any fancybox *callback*.

To get the `data-id` attribute's value (or any or more attributes), as in your example, you can use the `afterLoad` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox-buttons").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        // get (data) attributes from current element
        var attr1 = $(this.element).data("id"),
            attr2 = $(this.element).data("fancybox-group");
        alert(attr1 +", "+attr2);
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2n73A/1)</kbd>